# event_set (logstash ruby) does not give me a field?

Tags: ruby, logstash-grok

I may have misunderstood the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-api.html), but is not event_set supposed to give me a field that I can search for in (e.g.) kibana?

I've also looked at several posts, for which I think [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-date-filter-in-unix-ms-from-two-fields/99580/3) is the closest to describing my problem(?). I have tried the exact syntax as suggested by @magnusbaeck in this post too, without succeeding in getting a new field defined this way.

I can't seem to get the `event_set` to work as I expect, and I cannot figure out how I'm meant to do this with the syntax introduced with version 5.0.

I grok two fields from my log file, named TimeSpentMinutes and TimeSpentSeconds, and I know there are several posts about this, but not so many that I've been able to find *after* the change with v.5.0.

Anyway, my log looks something like this (I've edited a bit to simplify):

```
1012 2017-10-27 05:03:24 [  2:31] some message blablabla
```

I then run the following trying to convert the TimeSpentMinutes into seconds and add these seconds to the valule in TimeSpentSeconds, then put them to a new field called TimeSpent:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => ["^%{NUMBER:LogLineID} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:LogLineTime} \[%{SPACE}%{INT:TimeSpentMinutes}\:%{INT:TimeSpentSeconds}\] %{GREEDYDATA:LogText}$"]
    }
  }

  # Merge related minutes and seconds to one single value in seconds
  if [TimeSpentMinutes][TimeSpentMinutes] {
    ruby {
      code => 'event_set("TimeSpent", event_get("TimeSpentMinutes").to_f*60 + event_get("TimeSpentSeconds").to_f)'
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => ['TimeSpentMinutes', 'TimeSpentSeconds']
    }
  }
}
```

From this I get:

```
LogLineID = 1012
LogLineTime = 2017-10-27 05:03:24
TimeSpentMinutes = 2
TimeSpentSeconds = 31
LogText = some message blablabla
```

So far so good, but it does not seem like the ruby filter does anything? At least, I do not get the field `TimeSpent` that I expect.

Do I need to add some `add_field` in a mutate or ruby filter? Or is there something else that I've misunderstood? I do not see any error messages, so it seems at least the syntax is more or less ok, but there must be something that's off or missing.

Comment: On rereading your code I'm not sure about your if condition either... Not sure what you're trying to achieve but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341778/logstash-if-statement-with-regex-example) helps to check whether there's an integer in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You somewhat misunderstood the documentation. The correct syntax is `event.set` (note the dot instead of a underscore)

See the example from the docs you linked, it demonstrates getting and setting fields:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => 'event.set("lowercase_field", event.get("message").downcase)'
  }
}
```

Your line of ruby code might look like this in the end:

```
ruby {
      code => 'event.set("TimeSpent", event.get("TimeSpentMinutes").to_f*60 + event.get("TimeSpentSeconds").to_f)'
    }
```